# Video editing software for math/science videos?

Tags: technology-in-education, computer-programs

I've found some great advice on recording software, microphones etc. to create math videos with screen captured audio from my iPad showing my writing and audio so I can record and explanation.

I would like to have some software to edit these videos a little bit. I think they could benefit from:

1. Cutting out bits that have little audio or screen action.
2. Fast forwarding the video while keeping the audio at normal speed (then removing some of the dead spaces to compensate.)
3. Basic titles.
4. a little public domain music.
5. easy way to add on screen text, and still images to enrich the problems.

Most of the video editor reviews seem to center on live footage and that's not what I have. I remember from when I was much more interested in video about 10 years ago that speeding up footage could take forever-- but it must be better now? And my footage is very simple visually so it should compress better?

Are there any programs that are much better than say iMovie or some other basic editor for this purpose?

What about programs that organize clips? Helper applications?

I recently discovered GeoGebra and I've been using it for all kinds of graphics for my videos.

Comment: You want to do this on the iPad, and not on a conventional computer?  You mention iMovie, so maybe you will do it on a Macintosh?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like iMovie or a similar software would be plenty for your needs. If you want to get into other production, there is a bit of a learning curve and many resources online that can get you started.

Most of the high end video production software is expensive and does more than you could possibly need, but once you've picked a program, just jump onto YouTube and search for beginner tutorials. There are a bunch of them out there that detail different techniques and go over all the tools in the program.

All of this said, there's a reason that A/V guys go to college to get degrees to do what you're asking for.

Comment: I double majored in film during undergrad so ...  still I want simplicity to avoid the time-suck. does iMovie do time lapse? is it slow? I'll look into it.

Comment: I'm not sure what all you'll need, and what each package has, but you might check out Camtasia.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Vjay by algoriddim](https://www.algoriddim.com/vjay-ipad). It costs $9.99 on the iPad app market. The only requested feature that I'm not sure it has is on-screen text.